# Slider not updating itself

Tags: flutter

I saw another StackOverflow post, none of that worked for me.

I am a flutter newbie.

I am showing modal bottom sheet from a stateful widget called 'Home'

```
showMaterialModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      bounce: true,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
                      builder: (context) => SingleChildScrollView(
                        controller: ModalScrollController.of(context),
                        child: bookmark(id: books[index]['_id'], totalPages: int.parse(books[index]['total']), completedPages: int.parse(books[index]['done']),); 
               //another 'Stateful widget'
                    ),
                  );
```

Another stateful widget name 'bookmark' looks like this

```
     int toggleIndex = 0;
     double dragPercentage = 0;
     double dragUpdate = 0;

     //variables common to both main widget and this widget


    class bookmark extends StatefulWidget {
      final int totalPages;
      final int completedPages;
      final int id;
      bookmark({@required this.completedPages, @required this.totalPages, @required this.id});
      @override
      State<bookmark> createState() => _bookmarkState();
    }

    class _bookmarkState extends State<bookmark> {
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return
          Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [             
             
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.maxFinite,

                  child: CupertinoSlider(
                    value: dragUpdate,
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    onChanged: (double dragUpdate) {
                      setState(() {
                        dragUpdate = dragUpdate;
                        dragPercentage = dragUpdate * widget.totalPages;
                        pages.text = (dragPercentage / 100.0).toStringAsFixed(0);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              
            ],
          )
      );
  }
}
```

The slider is updating the value but is not updating itself.
to be clear, there are 2 stateful widgets named home and bookmark. I am calling showMaterialModalBottomSheet from home and building a bookmark.

what I tried?
I already tried to wrap my slider with a statefulbuilder and used its state to update the values.

Comment: `dragUpdate` should be declare inside `_bookmarkState` because `setState()` will only update the member variable declare inside it's statefull class. So variables outside of a class wont be updated.

Comment: Ok, but, I also want to access the variables from Home()

Comment: In that case you have to use a state management package like Provider or Bloc.